# PHP MySQL DB Connection practices

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

1. When my web app starts, a class1 connects to MySQL DB.
2. On ajax requests, class2 creates an object from class3. Both class2 and class3 connect to the DB.

At this point I get a 'too many connections' error.

What are the best practices on database connection for web apps?

Comment: you can reuse the same connection, you can also increase the allowed number of connections in the mysql configuration.

Comment: Are you the only one using that app? And are you sure you did not create a loop causing too many connections to the database (defaults to 100, so 3 connections should not trigger that)?

Comment: Use a wrapper class around your database connection that uses the Singleton pattern so that there is only ever one connection to the database per-script. eg: [this](http://sammitch.ca/2012/11/simple-php-pdo-wrapper-class/)

Comment: @Sammitch Recommending Singleton? Seriously? I had to comment it, because others may follow your suggestion ...

Comment: @KingCrunch is this not the *exact* case for using a Singleton? Would you like to elaborate on why it's supposedly such a bad idea?

Comment: @Sammitch There is no use-case for Singleton. The reasons to avoid it are the same for global variables, the Registry-Pattern and static methods/properties (in most cases): You have global cross-dependencies/-associations, that you cannot track down anymore sooner or later. So for your case: You want a second connection? Now you hack it into somehow.

Comment: @KingCrunch ruling all those things out the only thing left to solve OP's problem is to increase the number of connection slots in mySQL.

Comment: @sammitch - No need for a singleton... just create a connection and reuse it.